# To which Project should LibVLC dependencies be added?

Tags: c#, .net, project-reference, libvlcsharp

I have a Solution with .NET Framework Project `A` which builds a winforms application containing a class, `MyPlayer` which requires **LibVLCSharp**.  In order for the application to build and run correctly I had to add the following Nuget packages:

- LibVLCSharp
- LibVLCSharp.WinForms
- VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows

Now I want to move class `MyPlayer` to a separate .NET Standard class library, Project `B`, to separate out function from UI and so that it can be used by multiple other projects *targeted to different platforms*.  In order for `B` to compile I only had to add the **LibVLCSharp** Nuget package.  Then I set `B` as a Reference for `A`.

Obviously, Project `A` is going to require the other two Nuget packages somehow, but I am unsure to which project it is most appropriate to add them.  What makes the most sense in this situation?  Or is there really only one way it would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's a good question, and I don't know if it is properly documented on LibVLCSharp.

Short Answer:

- LibVLC must always be referenced on the executable project (A)
- WinForms isn't compatible with .net standard, so you can't reference it in B if you keep using netstandard.
- LibVLCSharp can be moved "up" in project B if you need it there.

Long answer:

Let's see the packages in detail:

- `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` : This package contains the required dlls files that are required to make libvlc work on Windows. It also contains msbuild files that are used to copy the DLLs to the output directory of your project. You need those files in your application, so you need to reference this package in `A`. (They won't be transitively copied by a Project reference)
- `LibVLCSharp.WinForms` : As stated [here](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/src/LibVLCSharp.WinForms/README.md), this package only support .NET framework 4.0 and above, and .net core 3.0 and above. You will not be able to add this package in `B`, unless you replace your `netstandard` constraint and use multi-targetting instead. It will only work where WinForms is available.
- `LibVLCSharp` can be referenced in project `B` without any issue. Since you're using .net standard, chances are you are also using the "SDK-style" csproj format and `PackageReference`. The dependency will then transitively be available in project A without adding it there.

If your point was having a player Form available in both .net framework and .net core, I'd recommend that you use multi targetting, by putting this in your B project:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net40;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

otherwise, if it's just for sharing non-ui code, you don't need the LibVLCSharp.WinForms dependency in B

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!  Your first bullet in the long answer was what I was most interested in, but your final comments helped as well, since I want project B to make sense as something multi-platform and sharable (and not UI-involved).  When I tried this I ended up not needing the WinForms reference at all, LibVLCSharp went on project B, and VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows went on project A.  Everything works as it should.