# dlls disappear when performing an incremental build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I am compiling a solution using Visual Studio 2019. This solution has two projects, we can call them Common and Program. Program depends on Common and Common depends on the NuGet packages `LibVLCSharp`, `LibVLCSharp.WPF` and `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows`.

If I clean and then build Program, everything is fine: the dlls are correctly copied in `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release`. But if I make any change to Program and compile it without cleaning it, the dlls relative to VLC disappear.

What can be the reason for the dlls to disappear?
In the visual studio UI I do not see the commands it is running when I compile the project. How can I debug it?

Comment: Were the DLL's copied manually, or as part of the NuGet packages themselves?

Comment: part of the NuGet packages

Comment: You can get it here https://send.firefox.com/download/08f48d8662a0429d/#8TKugBxrrSRbGpC4i0ogaA . As I said, clean Program, then compile it. in bin/Debug  you'll find libvlc/win-x86/libvlc* . Then just add an empty space to the MainWindow.xaml , compile Program without cleaning and you will not fild the dlls under bin/Debug/libvlc/win-x86 .

Comment: You could try to build with the diagnostic verbosity option

Comment: Files sent with Firefox Send expire after a while. This is not a good platform to share code for a StackOverflow question. It is better to host the code on github for example, where permalinks can be created, so that future readers can look at it and know if they have the same issue.

Comment: Ok, i put a copy on https://github.com/ocampana/missingdlls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are referencing `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` on your `Common` project rather than in your `Program` project. This is not a scenario that we support.

I wrote [this explanation about which project you should install LibVLC in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61485823/2663813).

In short, you should install the `LibVLC` package only into your application project, because we insert a build step that copies the files to the Output Folder of your project.

If you reference the LibVLC project in the `Common` project, there is no way we can copy the files to the `Program` project, because it is not known by MSBuild. You would then have to tell MSBuild to copy those files from `Common/bin/...` to `Project/bin/...`, but trust me, you don't want to mess with MSBuild.

EDIT: That doesn't mean that you can't use LibVLCSharp in your Common project. You can reference the LibVLCSharp packages in your `Common` project, because it only depends on `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` at runtime.